# Section based linguistic example numbering with brackets

Tags: numbering, cleveref, linguistics, examples, linguex

I would like to have examples in my document look like this:

> **Section 2**
>
> (2.1) This is an example.
>
> This is a reference to example (2.1).

That is:

- the section number appears both next to the example and in the reference to it
- both the labels and references to examples have brackets around them: I shouldn't have to do a whole lot of manual bracketing of \ref, i.e., not example (\ref{myexample}) for every single reference to every single example.
- have the example numbers reset to 1 at the beginning of each section
- ideally I want to use `cleveref` in order to minimise typing too :)

So far the closest I've got is with the `linguex` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\renewcommand{\theExNo}{(\thesection.\arabic{ExNo})}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{ExNo}{example}{examples}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\setcounter{ExNo}{0}\oldsection}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\ex. Example the first.\label{ex1}

I'd like to refer to \cref{ex1}.

\section{Second section}

\ex. Example the second.\label{ex2}

I'd like to refer to \cref{ex2}.

\end{document}
```

However the output of this looks like:

> **1 First section**
>
> (1) Example the first.
>
> I’d like to refer to example (1.1).
>
> **2 Second section**
>
> (1) Example the second.
>
> I’d like to refer to example (2.1).

That is, I've got the automatic bracketing in the references, the counter resetting, but the examples themselves are marked (1) rather than (1.1) and (2.1).

I am presently agnostic regarding the various linguistic example packages, so if you know how to make this work with a different one, I would be grateful for that too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The numbering of examples is hardwired in `linguex`; you can modify it by changing the corresponding command. Here's a commented minimal document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linguex}

% We want that the label to an example has also the section number
\renewcommand{\Exarabic}{\thesection.\arabic} 

% We want to reset the ExNo counter at each section
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{ExNo}{section}


\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{ExNo}{example}{examples}

% We want cross references of the form "example (1.1)"
\creflabelformat{ExNo}{(#2#1#3)}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\ex. Example the first.\label{ex1}

I'd like to refer to \cref{ex1}.

\section{Second section}

\ex. Example the second.\label{ex2}

I'd like to refer to \cref{ex2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! I've managed to achieve it with gb4e as well, and will supply that as another answer.

Answer (score 4):

My solution using `gb4e`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\thesection.\arabic{xnumi}}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{xnumi}{example}{examples}
\creflabelformat{xnumi}{(#2#1#3)}
 \let\oldsection\section
 \renewcommand{\section}{\setcounter{exx}{0}\oldsection}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{exe}
\ex Example the first.\label{ex1}
\end{exe}

I'd like to refer to \cref{ex1}.

\section{Second section}

\begin{exe}
\ex Example the second.\label{ex2}
\end{exe}

I'd like to refer to \cref{ex2}.

\end{document}
```

Presumably if using subexamples all the config for `xnumi` would need to be repeated for `xnumii`, `xnumiii` and `xnumiv`.

Comment: Instead of your redefinition of `\section` you can just use the `chngcntr` package and add `\counterwithin{exx}{section}`.