# Automatic Paragraph Numbers (\everypar only for paragraphs and not for \section and so on)

Tags: numbering, paragraphs

I want to write a specification and each **paragraph** should **automatically** be **numbered**. I found something similar in a book about fitness training:

[image]

I prepared a small MWE (**two-sided** layout):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Sadly I do not have a starting point for a solution. A manual solution would be to use margin notes.

> Ideally the solution does not include a command I have to write before
> every paragraph.

### Update 1

Question/Answer [Numbered paragraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15015) is pretty close:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[excludeor]{everyhook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip} % I added this, Manuel Kuehner
\newcounter{paragraphs}[section]
\begin{document}
\PushPostHook{par}{%
        \stepcounter{paragraphs}%
        \llap{\thesection.\theparagraphs\ \kern\parindent}%
}
\section{Foo}
\lipsum
\section{Bar}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

It creates an output like this:

[image]

So the output is not correct.

> The problem is here that every section etc. also gets the additional
> numbering.

### Update 2

Here's another close solution (in German): http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/5020

But there's the same problem that I need to use a command for every number.

### Update 3 [2020-11-07, i. e. 5 Years later]

- After using/trying this for about 1.5 years I stopped it.
- In hindsight, the comments (@egreg for example) were right and it used too many unwanted side effects.
- I am sorry that I do not have a better update.
- I ended up using `\subsubparagraph` and used it for every paragraph with a different formatting compared to the rest of the headings.

Comment: A counter and `\everypar` is probably the way to go.  I've written something like this ages ago - will see if I can find it.

Comment: Just a note: In Question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10513 they all say that changing \everypar it not a good idea.

Comment: Changing of some internals is always bad. However in your case I think it should be much easier to define a single command which puts a number at the beginning of the next paragraph. So you can avoid some complications with other packages and you are more flexibel (e.g. using a table or figure)

Comment: My answer would be similar to this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10513/automatically-assign-a-number-to-every-paragraph?rq=1

Comment: There are too many places where `\par` is used and a number should not appear: not only section titles, but also items in lists (including a single paragraph `center` environment). One could think to “conditional numbering”, disabling it in the special places. Not a task I'd undertake.

Comment: @egreg See my update (#3) :). You were right (no surprise) :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach using the `linguex` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text    
\usepackage{linguex}
% Counter format 
\renewcommand{\ExLBr}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\ExRBr}{}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57279/11604
% Reset \ex. at each section 
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{ExNo}{section}
% add section counter
\renewcommand{\Exarabic}{\thesection.\arabic} 
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\ex. \lipsum[2]\par
\ex. \lipsum[3]\par
\section{Second section}
\ex. \lipsum[3]\par
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** If yo do not want any command starting the paragraphs, use `\everypar` at your own risk ... you are warned in the comments.

In the next MWE, the macro `\NumPar` at the beginning of each section produce the same output that above. As example of the problems about using `\everypar`,  note that a new section cancel the numeration but do not restore the default indentation of 1em, so you must restore it manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent1em
\begin{document}
\def\NumPar{%
\parskip0.5em%
\parindent0em%
\everypar={%
\hangindent3em%
\addtocounter{subsection}{1}%
\makebox[3em][l]{\bfseries\thesubsection}%
}}%
\section{First section}
\NumPar
\lipsum[2]\par
\lipsum[3]\par
\everypar{}
\lipsum[3]\par
\section{Second section}
\NumPar % Or \parindent1em to return to normal paragraphs
\lipsum[3]\par
\lipsum[3]\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the \ex.?

Comment: @ManuelKuehner, see the edited answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe I can add \NumPar to a \section-hook and then I do not need to add it manually. Hook (not quite) for Section: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87996/

Comment: Allow me a question. Why is \everypar reseted on every \section? Does this apply to \chapter and so on too?

Comment: @ManuelKuehner Yes, because `\everypar` is used at low level by many other LaTeX commands,    among these  `\@@startsection`so, is changed by any sectioning level.  See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119758/why-does-everypar-not-work).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which is **non-automatic**, but a handy solution is using the `enumitem` package. Only `item`ize each paragraph in the `description` block:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text    
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{description}[style=unboxed,leftmargin=0.7cm]
\item[$\textbf{1.1}$]\lipsum[1]\par
\item[$\textbf{1.2}$]\lipsum[2]\par
\end{description}
\section{Second section}
\begin{description}[style=unboxed,leftmargin=0.7cm]
\item[$\textbf{2.1}$]\lipsum[3]\par
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As long as you're using `enumitem`, you might as well make it an `enumerate` and have the label automatically created for you.