# \everypar in section (or chapter) command not working

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs

> This is a follow up question of
>   [Automatic Paragraph Numbers (\everypar only for paragraphs and not for \section and so on)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263744).

I want to change `\everypar` in every section (or chapter). As soon as I use `\everypar`in the `\section` command I get an error. When I use a command then it works fine.

### Version 1 (not working)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{parskip}

% Version 1
% ----------------------------
% everypar in section
\let\OriginalSection\section%
\renewcommand{\section}{%
    \OriginalSection%
    \everypar={\marginpar[Testtext 1]{}}    
}

%% Version 2
%% ----------------------------
%% everypar in command
%\def\NumPar{%
%   \everypar={\marginpar[]{Testtext 2}}%
%}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
%\NumPar

\blindtext

\blindtext

\section{Second section}
%\NumPar

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
\@@par
l.25 \section
{First section}
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)
```

### Version 2 (working but not preferred)

Mind the `\NumPar` command in the code!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{parskip}

%% Version 1
%% ----------------------------
%% everypar in section
%\let\OriginalSection\section%
%\renewcommand{\section}{%
%   \OriginalSection%
%   \everypar={\marginpar[Testtext 1]{}}    
%}

% Version 2
% ----------------------------
% everypar in command
\def\NumPar{%
    \everypar={\marginpar[]{Testtext 2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\NumPar

\blindtext

\blindtext

\section{Second section}
\NumPar

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Which gives me the output

[image]

### What I Want

I want to use the `\everypar` command in **Version 1** because then I do not have to add the command `\NumPar` manually as in **Version 2**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in

```
\OriginalSection%
\everypar
```

you are passing `\everypar` as the argument to the original section.

You can do as below to set `\everpar` after the section argument has been read. Need to work a bit harder if you need star forms and optional arguments of `\section`.

It really is not supported to set `\everypar` like this *lots* of things that use paragraph settings internally are likely to break,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{parskip}

% Version 1
% ----------------------------
% everypar in section
\let\OriginalSection\section%
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
    \OriginalSection{#1}%
    \everypar={\marginpar[Testtext 1]{}}% 
}

%% Version 2
%% ----------------------------
%% everypar in command
%\def\NumPar{%
%   \everypar={\marginpar[]{Testtext 2}}%
%}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
%\NumPar

\blindtext

\blindtext

\section{Second section}
%\NumPar

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not have another solution. I would be happy to get another way (see original question, this is a follow up).