# Changing date format in datetime2

Tags: datetime2

Using the `datetime2` package, how do I tell `\today` to display the date in the format: 'Fri, March 1, 2019'?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below I define a new date style called `mydateformat`, and then use it with `\DTMsetdatestyle{mydateformat}`.

[image: resulting date format]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[calc,showdow,english]{datetime2}

\DTMnewdatestyle{mydateformat}{%
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{%
    \DTMshortweekdayname{##4},\space% short weekday,
    \DTMmonthname{##2}\nobreakspace%  (full) Month
    \number##3,\space%                day,
    \number##1%                       year
  }%
  \renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}

\begin{document}

\today

\DTMsetdatestyle{mydateformat}

\today

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Professor, could you please help me in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478218/changing-the-date  I want that the letter t will be separated a bit from the number 7. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Schüler: See [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478605/5764) that uses [`datetime2`](//ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) and introduces a small space `\,` before the ordinal day/number.