# Changing the date

Tags: date

```
        \documentclass[a4paper,10pt,demo    ]{article} %
    \usepackage{pifont} %bouni
    %-----accent
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      %-----
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
     \usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
      \usepackage{wrapfig}
      \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% dimension ancien des marges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% style des sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
      \usepackage{sectsty}
      \sectionfont{%                        % Change font of \section 
         command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
     \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Macros %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}     % Vertical space macro
      \newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
        \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}
      \newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{ % Slogan}{optional)
    \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1}
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}
      %%% ------------------------------------------------------------
      \pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \begin{document}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Photo et title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %---------------------------
   %---------------------------
   \MyName{Name Name}
    \MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae \\ \null\hfill  (\today)}
    %\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae (October 2016)}
    %---------------------------
    \sepspace  % Si on ajoute encore \sepspace on aura plus d'espace
    $$$$
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%% Personal details%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section*{Informations personelles}

    \end{document}
```

> I want to add ''th'' in the date as follows

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is here

1. to find the right layout for your wished date (month day-with-ord, year) and
2. to change the distance between number and ord.

To test this two points please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB,en-CA,en-US]{datetime2}

%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\DTMenglishordinal}% <cmd>
%  {#1 \DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <search>
%  {#1\,\DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <replace>
%  {}{}% <success><failure>


\begin{document}

british: 
\DTMsetstyle{en-GB}\today.
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise} % ,monthyearsep={,\space},abbr
\DTMsetstyle{en-GB}\emph{\today} \today

canadian:
\DTMlangsetup[en-CA]{ord=raise} % ,monthyearsep={,\space},abbr  ,ordsep={\,}
\DTMsetstyle{en-CA}\emph{\today} \today

american:
\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{ord=raise} % ,monthyearsep={,\space},abbr
\DTMsetstyle{en-US}\emph{\today} \today

\end{document}
```

Its result shows you that you can choose the canadian or american variant to get your wished date layout.  Because you used italic font in your document I showed in the MWE above italic and normal text for the date.

[image: variants]

You can see that in this variant the distance between number and ord is a little bit greater than in your result, but if you want more distance, please uncomment the lines

```
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\DTMenglishordinal}% <cmd>
%  {#1 \DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <search>
%  {#1\,\DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <replace>
%  {}{}% <success><failure>
```

in the MWE above to activate an patch. This patch adds an smal skip `\,` after the number (represented with `#1` in the code. Now you get the result:

[image: date with smal skip]

Okay, now we can include the found code (I choosed american variant) into your code:

```
\documentclass[%
  a4paper,
  10pt,
  demo
]{article}

\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2} % <=======================================
\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{ord=raise}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % <===============================================
\patchcmd{\DTMenglishordinal}% <cmd> <==================================
  {#1 \DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <search>
  {#1\,\DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\usepackage{pifont} %bouni

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{%                        % Change font of \section 
  command % <=================================================== ???????
  \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
  \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}}

\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}     % Vertical space macro
\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
        \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}
\newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{ % Slogan}{optional)
    \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1}
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers


\begin{document}

\MyName{Name Name}
\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae \\ \null\hfill  (\DTMsetstyle{en-US}\today)} % <=======================

\sepspace  % Si on ajoute encore \sepspace on aura plus d'espace

\section*{Informations personelles}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: your code with correction]

The red underlined "command" commes from the line I marked in the code with `<====== ?????`. Is that what you want? If not delete the line with `command` in the code.

Comment: Please how can I change `\today` by another date and without lossing american variant? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See documentation datetime2 with `texdoc datetime2`, page 10. You can use `\DTMdisplaydate{2019}{4}{7}{-1}` or you can use `\DTMsavedate{mydate}{2019-04-9}` to save a special date and use it with `\DTMusedate{mydate}` instead `\today` ...

Answer (score 1):

Using `datetime` package, ([see](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/datetime/datetime.pdf) `datetime.sty` pdf, on p:8):

```
     \documentclass[a4paper,10pt,demo    ]{article} %
      \usepackage{datetime}
      \newdateformat{dashdate}{%
\twodigit{\THEDAY}-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\THEYEAR}
\newdateformat{usvardate}{%
\monthname[\THEMONTH] \ordinal{DAY}, \THEYEAR}

    \usepackage{pifont} %bouni
    %-----accent
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      %-----
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
     \usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
      \usepackage{wrapfig}
      \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% dimension ancien des marges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% style des sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
      \usepackage{sectsty}
      \sectionfont{%                        % Change font of \section 
         command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
     \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Macros %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}     % Vertical space macro
      \newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
        \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}
      \newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{ % Slogan}{optional)
    \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1}
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}
      %%% ------------------------------------------------------------
      \pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \begin{document}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Photo et title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %---------------------------
   %---------------------------
   \MyName{Name Name}
    \MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae \\ \null\hfill  (\usvardate\today)}
    %\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae (October 2016)}
    %---------------------------
    \sepspace  % Si on ajoute encore \sepspace on aura plus d'espace
    $$$$
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%% Personal details%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section*{Informations personelles}

    \end{document}

  [1]:
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please can I separate a bit the letter t from the number 7?

Comment: Please also why you changed `\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae \\ \null\hfill  (\today)}` by `\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae \\ \null\hfill  (\usvardate\today)}`? Thanks

Comment: Or you can use `level` option to pass `datetime`, e.g, `\usepackage[level]{datetime}`. The `th` is placed next to date, not uppercase.

Comment: In your opinion, what is the best way? Thanks

Comment: `usvardate` is the name of the new dateformat. See my code. It is defined after `\usepackage{datetime}`.

Comment: Best way is up to you. Both of them are acceptable. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. My last question: please I don't understand why you used `\null\hfill  (\usvardate\today)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90731/discussion-between-ferahfeza-and-schuler).

Comment: I answered in chat.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses a [`datetime2`](//ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) approach to set the ordinal date, similar to what is proposed in [ferahfeza's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478223/5764). Additionally, a minor adjustment in the placement of the ordinal is introduced:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[calc,english]{datetime2}
\DTMnewdatestyle{usvardate}{%
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{%
    \DTMmonthname{##2} \ordinalnum{##3}, \number##1 }%
  \renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand{\fmtord}[1]{\,\fc@textsuperscript{#1}}% Add \, before ordinal number
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
  \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1
  \par \normalsize \normalfont}
\newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{ % Slogan}{optional)
  \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1}
  \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\begin{document}

\MyName{Name Name}
\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae \\ \null\hfill  (\DTMsetdatestyle{usvardate}\today)}

\end{document}
```