# Understanding LaTeX 2e's \@esphack

Tags: spacing, macros, latex-base, horizontal

I'm reading source2e.pdf and I have problems in understanding the sense of the definition of LaTeX 2ε's `\@esphack`:

Commands like `\label{...}` , which themselves do not/shall not produce any visible output, might in the source/in the .tex-input-file be surrounded by spaces. If so, you don't want two space-tokens as this would double the horizontal glue.

If I got it right, `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` are there for avoiding the coming into being of a space-token after tokenizing and processing the command in case there already came one into being before tokenizing and processing the command.

So let's look at the definition of `\@bsphack`:

```
> \@bsphack=macro:
->\relax \ifhmode \@savsk \lastskip \@savsf \spacefactor \fi .
l.1    \show\@bsphack
```

In words:

When in horizontal mode or in restricted horizontal mode, then save the value of `\lastskip` to `\@savsk` and save the value of `\spacefactor` to `\@savsf`.

Now let's look at the definition of `\@esphack`:

```
> \@esphack=macro:
->\relax \ifhmode \spacefactor \@savsf \ifdim \@savsk >\z@ \ifdim \lastskip =\z
@ \nobreak \hskip \z@skip \fi \ignorespaces \fi \fi .
l.2    \show\@esphack
```

In words:

When in horizontal mode or in restricted horizontal mode, then:

- restore the value of `\spacefactor` to the value saved as `\savsf`.
- In case `\@savsk` is larger than zero, i.e., in case there was some horizontal glue before carrying out the command which at its start called `\@bsphack`, then do
  `\ifdim \lastskip =\z@ \nobreak \hskip \z@skip \fi \ignorespaces`
  .

I understand that `\ignorespaces` will make sense as there was already some horizontal glue before carrying out the command which at its start called `\@bsphack`.

But I don't understand what the
`\ifdim \lastskip =\z@ \nobreak \hskip \z@skip \fi`
-part is good for.

What is the sense of this?

In the situation where this is carried out, the saved value in `\@savsk` is larger than `\z@`, thus one can conclude that something from within the command which at its start called `\@bsphack` did change the value of `\lastskip` to `\z@`.

But doing something like `\nobreak\hskip\z@skip` will not revert that change/will not restore `\lastskip` to its previous value.

Thus: What is the gist/sense/benefit of performing that `\hskip` of zero-width?

If you wish `\lastskip` to be restored, shouldn't it then be something like:

```
\def\@esphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \spacefactor\@savsf
    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
      \ifdim\lastskip=\z@
        \nobreak
        \hskip-\@savsk
        \nobreak
        \hskip\@savsk
        % the total skip is zero and \lastskip is restored.
      \fi
      \ignorespaces
    \fi
  \fi
}%
```

Or perhaps just

```
\def\@esphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \spacefactor\@savsf %now \spacefactor is restored.
    \nobreak
    \hskip-\@savsk
    \nobreak
    \hskip\@savsk
    % the total skip is zero and \lastskip is restored.
    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
      \ignorespaces
    \fi
  \fi
}%
```

Is it possible that in some previous release, it was done this way and in later releases somebody erroneously "optimized" the 
`\nobreak\hskip-\@savsk\nobreak\hskip\@savsk` to `\nobreak\hskip\z@skip`, overlooking that this won't restore `\lastskip` any more?

If I understand correctly, you need to restore `\lastskip` correctly as otherwise things with consecutive sequences of `\@bsphack..\@esphack`, e.g., `\label{foo}\label{bar}` won't work correctly:

If by now you do something like
`A \label{foo} \label{bar} A`
or
`A \label{foo}\label{bar} A`
, `\lastskip` will in any case be 0 after `\label{foo}` which affects the behavior of `\label{bar}` because with `\label{bar}` `\@savsk` will not be larger than `\z@` any more so that `\ignorespaces` won't get carried out although it should be carried out!

With the example below you can see a subtle difference when redefining `\@esphack` so that it restores `\lastskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A\label{1}B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A\label{1}B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{2} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A \label{2} B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{3}\label{4} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A \label{3}\label{4} B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|  \label{5} \label{6} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil}  A \label{5} \label{6} B

\makeatletter
\def\@esphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \spacefactor\@savsf
    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
      \ifdim\lastskip=\z@
        \nobreak
        \hskip-\@savsk
        \nobreak
        \hskip\@savsk
        % the total skip is zero and \lastskip is restored.
      \fi
      \ignorespaces
    \fi
  \fi
}%
\makeatother

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A\label{a}B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A\label{a}B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{b} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A \label{b} B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{c}\label{d} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A \label{c}\label{d} B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{e} \label{f} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil}  A \label{e} \label{f} B

\end{document}
```

[image]

Does my modification of `\@esphack` have drawbacks?

Am I overlooking some caveat/something relevant?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You see more change comments, and older versions in the source:

```
% \begin{macro}{\@esphack}
%   Companion to |\@bsphack|.  If this command is not properly paired
%   with |\@bsphack| one might end up with a low-level \TeX{} error:
%   ``BAD spacefactor''. One possible cause is calling |\@bsphack| in
%   vertical mode, then doing something that gets you (sometimes) into
%   horizontal mode and finally calling |\@esphack|. Even if no error
%   is generated that is wrong, because |\@esphack| will then use the
%   saved values for |\@savsk| and |\@savsf| from some earlier
%   invocation of |\@bsphack| which will have nothing to do with the
%   current situation.
% \changes{v1.3d}{2015/01/11}{Allow hyphenation (Donald Arseneau pr/3498) (latexrelease)}
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</2ekernel>
%<latexrelease>\IncludeInRelease{2018/10/10}%
%<latexrelease>                 {\@esphack}{hyphenation and nobreak after space hack}%
%<*2ekernel|latexrelease>
\def\@esphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \spacefactor\@savsf
    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
%    \end{macrocode}
% \changes{v1.3f}{2015/11/07}
%         {Only space if there is no space at the end of the hlist latex/4443}
%    \begin{macrocode}
      \ifdim\lastskip=\z@ 
        \nobreak \hskip\z@skip
      \fi
      \ignorespaces
    \fi
%    \end{macrocode}
% \changes{v1.3i}{2018/10/10}
%         {Don't introduce breakpoints if @nobreak is true and after sections}
%    \begin{macrocode}
  \else
    \ifvmode
      \if@nobreak\nobreak\else\if@noskipsec\nobreak\fi\fi
    \fi
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
  \fi}%
%</2ekernel|latexrelease>
%<latexrelease>\EndIncludeInRelease
%<latexrelease>\IncludeInRelease{2015/10/01}%
%<latexrelease>                 {\@esphack}{hyphenation and nobreak after space hack}%
%<latexrelease>\def\@esphack{%
%<latexrelease>  \relax
%<latexrelease>  \ifhmode
%<latexrelease>    \spacefactor\@savsf
%<latexrelease>    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
%<latexrelease>      \ifdim\lastskip=\z@ 
%<latexrelease>        \nobreak \hskip\z@skip
%<latexrelease>      \fi
%<latexrelease>      \ignorespaces
%<latexrelease>    \fi
%<latexrelease>  \fi}%
%<latexrelease>\EndIncludeInRelease
%<latexrelease>\IncludeInRelease{2015/01/01}%
%<latexrelease>                 {\@esphack}{hyphenation and nobreak after space hack}%
%<latexrelease>\def\@esphack{%
%<latexrelease>  \relax
%<latexrelease>  \ifhmode
%<latexrelease>    \spacefactor\@savsf
%<latexrelease>    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
%<latexrelease>      \nobreak \hskip\z@skip
%<latexrelease>      \ignorespaces
%<latexrelease>    \fi
%<latexrelease>  \fi}%
%<latexrelease>\EndIncludeInRelease
%<latexrelease>\IncludeInRelease{0000/00/00}%
%<latexrelease>                 {\@esphack}{hyphenation and nobreak after space hack}%
%<latexrelease>\def\@esphack{%
%<latexrelease>  \relax
%<latexrelease>  \ifhmode
%<latexrelease>    \spacefactor\@savsf
%<latexrelease>    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
%<latexrelease>      \ignorespaces
%<latexrelease>    \fi
%<latexrelease>  \fi}%
%<latexrelease>\EndIncludeInRelease
%<*2ekernel>
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
```

Basically the bit you query, you need to add a space (or zero width) so as not to inhibit hyphenation, and then need to add the `\nobreak` so the space doesn't introduce a breakpoint.

---

Splitting the 0pt skip into `\hskip-\zzz\hskip\zzz` works better here as you know how the following `\lastskip` test is being used, however it leaves the horizontal list slightly vulnerable to any following `\unskip` that is removing a skip (rather than just testing it) as it will only remove half of the pair leaving a possibly unintended negative skip in the list.

I came up with this table example although arguably the result is also better in this case as the remaining negative skip cancels out the original space before the first index.. But other reasonable uses of `\unskip` would need to be checked....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox\mybox
\makeindex
\tabcolsep=0pt
\begin{document}

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A\label{1}B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A\label{1}B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{2} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A \label{2} B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{3}\label{4} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A \label{3}\label{4} B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|  \label{5} \label{6} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil}  A \label{5} \label{6} B

\begin{tabular}{|r|}
A A \index{A}\\
B B \index{B}\\
\end{tabular}


\makeatletter
\def\@esphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \spacefactor\@savsf
    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
      \ifdim\lastskip=\z@
        \nobreak
        \hskip-\@savsk
        \nobreak
        \hskip\@savsk
        % the total skip is zero and \lastskip is restored.
      \fi
      \ignorespaces
    \fi
  \fi
}%
\makeatother

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A\label{a}B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A\label{a}B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{b} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A \label{b} B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{c}\label{d} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A \label{c}\label{d} B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{e} \label{f} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil}  A \label{e} \label{f} B

\begin{tabular}{|r|}
A A \index{A}\\
B B \index{B}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

Rather than use `\ifdim\lastskip>0pt` as a test for "is there preceding glue" I think we could use the e-tex `\ifnum\lastnodetype=11` test to avoid adding spurious -ve/+ve glue pairs or spurious 1sp glue nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox\mybox
\makeindex
\tabcolsep=0pt
\begin{document}

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A\label{1}B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A\label{1}B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{2} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A \label{2} B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{3}\label{4} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A \label{3}\label{4} B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|  \label{5} \label{6} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil}  A \label{5} \label{6} B

\begin{tabular}{|r|}
A A \index{A}\\
B B \index{B}\\
\end{tabular}


\makeatletter
\def\@bsphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \@savsk\lastskip
    \ifdim\@savsk=\z@\ifnum\lastnodetype=11 \@savsk1sp \fi\fi
    \@savsf\spacefactor
  \fi}


% \def\@esphack{%
%   \relax
%   \ifhmode
%     \spacefactor\@savsf
%     \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
%       \ifdim\lastskip=\z@
%         \nobreak
%         \hskip1sp
%         % the total skip is zero and \lastskip is restored.
%       \fi
%       \ignorespaces
%     \fi
%   \fi
% }%

\makeatother

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A\label{a}B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A\label{a}B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{b} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A \label{b} B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{c}\label{d} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil} A \label{c}\label{d} B

\par\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\verb*|A \label{e} \label{f} B|:
\end{lrbox}\hbox to 4.5cm{\usebox\mybox\hfil}  A \label{e} \label{f} B

\begin{tabular}{|r|}
A A \index{A}\\
B B \index{B}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just added another example to my question to make my point about consecutive commands that are wrapped into `\@bsphack..\@esphack` clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see. But wouldn't it be better to add that space (of zero width) in a way which also restores `\lastskip` so that one can have consecutive commands that don't produce visible output in a row? If by now you do something like `A \label{foo} \label{bar} B` , `\lastskip` will in any case be 0 after `\label{foo}` which affects the behavior of `\label{bar}` because with `\label{bar}` `\@savsk` will not be larger than `\z@` any more so that `\ignorespaces` won't get carried out although it should be carried out? Is `\nobreak\hskip-\@savsk\nobreak\hskip\@savsk` unsafe?

Comment: To be honest: It is not clear to me what is meant by "not to inhibit hyphenation". Do people intend to place, e.g., `\label` into the middle of a word? If so: What is the insertion of (zero-width-)glue good for in the context of not inhibiting hyphenation?

Comment: @Questioner see the bug report mentioned above, with the original definition words following a figure environment, or `\index{..}` were not hyphenated https://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?category=LaTeX&responsible=anyone&state=anything&keyword=&pr=latex%2F3498&search=

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about hyphenation. Does changing `\nobreak\hskip\z@skip` to `\nobreak\hskip-\@savsk\nobreak\hskip\@savsk` have any drawbacks/pitfalls? (I edited my question for pointing out why I think that restoring `\lastskip` is necessary for the case of having consecutive commands whose definitions are wrapped in `\@bsphack..\@esphack`.)

Comment: @Questioner the modification suggestion is not unreasonable but it's a tricky area and I'd need to think about whether it has drawbacks, ending with a -ve and +skip means that `\lastskip` sees a positive skip at a place where there is no visible space, which might be bad in other contexts, I'd need to think about it. You could make a change suggestion at the new issue tracker at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues so we don't lose the suggestion (you can reference this post)

Comment: Seems with that modification `\lastskip` sees that positive skip (only?) in case `\@savsk` was positive due to a chain of consecutive `\@bsphack..\@esphack` that was preceded by a positive skip/a visible space...  (By the way: I implemented a similar `\@bsphack/\@esphack`-variant in my answer to [Generating a Persistent and Unique IDs (for Requirements in a Specification)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474396/118714) )

Comment: @UlrichDiez yes but that isn't the case I'm worried about, it is cases where this is followed by uses of  `\unskip` rather than `\lastskip`, I added an example above (although not clearly bad example)

Comment: @Questioner A perhaps safer alternative than `\nobreak\hskip-\@savsk\nobreak\hskip\@savsk`  would be `\nobreak\hskip1sp ` that would keep a single glue node but be enough to trigger the "positive skip" case in a following space hack.

Comment: @Questioner I added a new version testing the last node type, we might use this....