# Automatic Paragraph Numbers [2021, Using LaTeX's 2020's New Hook Management]

Tags: paragraphs, hooks

- This is a **2021 follow-up** question to my [question from **2015**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263744).
- I want to add to **every text paragraph** an **number automatically** ([see original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263744)).
  [image]
- In 2015, user [@Fran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11604/) warned me regarding the solution at the time.

> Edit: If yo [sic!] do not want any command starting the paragraphs, use
> \everypar at your own risk ... you are warned in the comments.

- The same is true for user [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427):

> There are too many places where \par is used and a number should not
> appear: not only section titles, but also items in lists (including a
> single paragraph center environment). One could think to “conditional
> numbering”, disabling it in the special places. Not a task I'd
> undertake.

- Recently, I saw that there is a new [new hook management](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/#documentation-of-the-new-hook-management) as of **2020**.

[image]

> The hook management introduced in 2020 is largely intended for package
> developers. However, most of the available hooks can also be useful
> for document authors.

- **Question:** Does the [new hook management](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/#documentation-of-the-new-hook-management) offer an easier way to number each text paragraph without having the risks/issues that were raised in 2015 by **egreg** and **Fran**?
- **Remark:** If yes, a separate follow-up question would be how to access the numbers: Referencing them in a `\label{}` and `\ref{}` pattern.

The MWE shows a not working version that shows the problems (numbers in unwanted places like questions, figures, headings, ...). The MWE is just a modified copy of my [MWE from 2015](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263744) - please do not consider the code and used packages too much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[excludeor]{everyhook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{parskip}
\newcounter{paragraphs}[section]

\newcommand{\myFillerAux}{ Test dummy text that has no meaning. }
\newcommand{\myFiller}{\myFillerAux\myFillerAux\myFillerAux\myFillerAux\myFillerAux\myFillerAux}

\begin{document}
\PushPostHook{par}{%
        \stepcounter{paragraphs}%
        \llap{\thesection.\theparagraphs\ \kern\parindent}%
}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test 1}
\myFiller

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\section{Test 2}
\myFiller

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can use the new hooks to add numbers, but you still will need something to disable the addition in unwanted places like section titles.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. Feel free to convert your comment to an answer and I will accept it.